# Como puedo crear una vista en Oracle?

Tags: oracle, vistas

Como puedo crear una vista sencilla que solo me ejecute un query como:

```
-- PC1
SELECT 'Computadora 1' as "Server", "Nombre", "Apellido", "FechaIngreso", "Estado"
  FROM tabla1@bdd1 a
WHERE a."Estado"= '1'
-- PC2
SELECT 'Computadora 2' as "Server", "Nombre", "Apellido", "FechaIngreso", "Estado"
  FROM tabla1@bdd2 b
WHERE b."Estado"= '1';
/
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.vista 
AS
-- PC1
SELECT 'Computadora 1' as "Server", "Nombre", "Apellido", "FechaIngreso", "Estado"
  FROM tabla1@bdd1 a
WHERE a."Estado"= '1'
UNION ALL
-- PC2
SELECT 'Computadora 2' as "Server", "Nombre", "Apellido", "FechaIngreso", "Estado"
  FROM tabla1@bdd2 b
WHERE b."Estado"= '1';
/
```

--Para ejecutar la vista

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.VISTA;
```